# Perl process crashes after handling signal

Tags: perl, signals, daemon

I'm trying to make rereading  config file for simple perl daemon on SIGHUP.
I'm trying

```
use sigtrap qw/handler rereadconf HUP/;
```

but after executing "rereadconf" procedure process stops
i'm also trying

```
%SIG{HUP} = \&rereadconf;
sub rereadconf{
.... mycode
print "procedure executed\n";
};
```

but result was the same, after executing procedure program stops.
So how can i make that process continue execution after signal handling?

Comment: The program resume as soon as you exit the handler. If it is actually caused by the signal and not something you do in the handler, best guess: You've interrupted a C library call that wasn't prepared to be interrupted. It needs better error handling.

Comment: Where does it "stop"?

Comment: @ikegami   Can it be because of using Socket? so i need handle error?

Comment: Programs don't stop. They block waiting for something. What is your program waiting for?

Comment: @ikegami It's waiting in cycle when client connects, if you wanna see source [link](http://pastebin.com/7YTX35Tx)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in cycle". What line?

Comment: There's no signal handler in that code. Did you post the right code?

Comment: @ikegami as i understand cycle is 57 line. Here is correct code [link](http://pastebin.com/FubYj0vK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program *exits* because the `accept` returns false because it got interrupted by a signal. You want

```
while (1) {
    my $client = $srv->accept();
    if (!$client) {
        next if $!{EINTR};
        die(sprintf(STDERR "[%s] accept: %s\n", basename($0), $!));
    }

    print(STDERR "accepted new client\n");
    serve_client($client);
}
```